# How do I remove the library paths that qmake automatically adds to the linker options

Tags: c++, qt4, qt-creator, qmake

Wanted to try using qt creator (coming from eclipse cdt) and I'm trying to get my project to build.  Unfortunately, qmake is adding -L/usr/lib to the linker options by itself, making it link to the wrong version of a library, and I can't figure out how to remove it.

I've tried doing "LIBS = " in the project file, as well as "LIBS -= -L/usr/lib", but it seems to be adding the option after it reads the settings from the project file.  Anyone know if there's a conf file somewhere (e.g. mkspecs directory) where I can comment this out?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from qmake itself. It puts `qt_libspath` into link flags. It can be changed by either configuring and compiling Qt with a different directory prefix, or by modifying the qmake binary itself.

An easy solution for you could be to create a filesystem-level link to the correct library version with a different name. That is, if you have `/usr/lib/libfoo.so` and `myfoo/lib/libfoo.so`, create a link `libmyfoo.so -> myfoo/lib/libfoo.so` and link with `-lmyfoo` instead of `-lfoo`.

Comment: I believe it's linking to the wrong version of libstdc++, which I don't explicitly add to the linker options.  It looks as though it's coming from QT_INSTALL_LIBS, which I can change using "qmake -set", but will probably mess up a bunch of other stuff.  Sucks that they force that in the linker flags.